# Mapping dynamic nosql document to java object

Tags: java, json, jackson, nosql

I have the following JSON

```
{
  "id":"wer_ereeyudhk567",
  "product":"Phone",
  "details": {
               "name" :"Nexsus 6",
               "cpu": "quadCore",
               "ram": "3 gb"
             }
}
```

and needs to be mapped to a java object, but the "details"  object  keeps changing based on product, like if product is "tablet" the number of fields in "details" will be different.How do I model this kind of data where number of fields can be dynamic and depend on "product" ?.In loosely typed languages like javascript you can add a field dynamically to object.Is there a way we can add a property/field dynamically to a java object?

Answer (score 0):

You can you Map for details to solve the dynamic data case.

```
public class Product {
    private String id;
    private String product;
    private Map<String, Object> details;
}
```

Using:

```
String json = "{  'id':'wer_ereeyudhk567',  'product':'Phone',  'details': {  'name' :'Nexsus 6',  'cpu': 'quadCore',  'ram': '3 gb', 'isNew': true, 'quantity': 100}}";
Product product = new Gson().fromJson(json, Product.class);

System.out.println(product.getDetails());
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but if I use Map<String, **String**>  then I am converting all values into String, I am loosing the data type information { numeric, boolean  etc}.Can I have a work around for storing the type as well ?. Thanks

Comment: Of course, you can change Map<String, String> by Map<String, Object> and cast the value if needed. I will edit the answer for you.

Answer (score 0):

Java Model for dynamic nosql document[product document]

```
public class Product {
    private String id;
    private String product;
    private Map<String, Object> details; //details might contains another objects
}
```

Jackson http://jackson.codehaus.org/ is a High-performance JSON processor Java library and used to convert Java object to / from JSON.

Convert your JSON to java object and vice-versa:

```
//1. Convert JSON to Java object
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Product productObject = mapper.readValue(JSONSource, Product.class); //JSONSource may be file or String
System.out.println(productObject.getXXX());

//2. Convert Java object to JSON format
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.writeValue(JSONSource, productObject);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but again I don't know  what lies in the Object whether is it a simple data type like string, numeric, boolean or a complex type like another nested JSON .Is there way to store the type information as well which will be helpful in casting back to java object. Thanks